# Can you explain me this function I didn't understand and how to convert it in "normal" function?

Tags: javascript

I find this javascript function on Internet and I don't understand how it works.

```
  (function(o) {
Number.getOrdinalFor = function(intNum, includeNumber) {
  return (includeNumber ? intNum : '') + (o[((intNum = Math.abs(intNum % 100)) - 20) % 10] || o[intNum] || 'th');
};
 })([, 'st', 'nd', 'rd']);
```

And can I convert it to a normal function like :

```
function getOrdinalFor (intNum, includeNumber) {
  // code
}
```

Comment: This code has been purposefully obfuscated, which is going to make it difficult for people to help out. But yes, you can reverse engineer this function and make it more readable. This is an immediately invoked function that adds functionality (a `getOrdinalFor` function) to the Number module.

Comment: Thank you for this first element of answer, I didn't know Immediately-invoked function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code returns an ordinal for a given number, for instance

```
Number.getOrdinalFor(1)       // returns "st"
Number.getOrdinalFor(2)       // returns "nd"
Number.getOrdinalFor(3)       // returns "rd"
Number.getOrdinalFor(4, true) // returns "4th"
                   //     ^ include number in output
```

To convert it to a regular function that can be called like

```
getOrdinalFor(1);
```

would be as simple as

```
function getOrdinalFor(intNum, includeNumber) {
    var o = [, 'st', 'nd', 'rd'];
    return (includeNumber ? intNum : '') + (o[((intNum = Math.abs(intNum % 100)) - 20) % 10] || o[intNum] || 'th');
}
```

---

Somewhat more readable, with comments

```
function getOrdinalFor(intNum, includeNumber) {
    var ordinals = [, 'st', 'nd', 'rd'];        // the ordinals, except "th", in an array, 
                                                // with the first index starting at 1

    var start    = includeNumber ? intNum : ''; // start with the number, or empty string
                                                // depending on includeNumber argument

    intNum     = Math.abs(intNum % 100);        // set intNum to the result of "modulus 100" on it self
                                                // this shortens down hundreds, thousands, and bigger
                                                // numbers to max two digits. For instance 
                                                // 2 = 2
                                                // 12 = 12
                                                // 233 = 33
                                                // 3444 = 44
                                                // 111111111 = 11
                                                // ...etc

    var calc   = (intNum - 20) % 10;            // then subtract 20, and do "modulus" 10
                                                // this shortens it to one integer, 
                                                // positive or negative, for instance
                                                // 2 = -8
                                                // 12 = -8
                                                // 33 = 3
                                                // 44 = 4
                                                // 11 = -9
                                                // ...etc


    var result = ordinals[calc] || ordinals[intNum] || 'th';  // start at the left hand, 
                                                              // and return first truthy value

    // for instance, using the results of the numbers above
    // ordinals[-8] does not exist (falsy), move along, ordinals[2] is "nd", so return "2nd"
    // ordinals[-8] does not exist (falsy), move along, ordinals[12] is falsy as well, so return "12th"
    // ordinals[3] is truthy, so return "33rd"
    // ...etc

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to your conversion and Calvin's answer I understand better now . I would like a last explanation on how this piece of code works :
    (x || y || z)

Comment: "return first truthy value"  I understand perfectly now, thank you.